# Use some existing bindings in a destructuring assignment

Tags: rust

I know that one can destructure tuples and other things in `let` statements:

```rust
fn foo() -> (u8, u8) {
    (1, 2)
}

fn main() {
    let (x, y) = foo();
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);  // prints "1, 2"
}
```

Since Rust 1.59 one can also re-use existing bindings:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let mut y = 0;
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);  // prints "0, 0"
    (x, y) = foo();
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);  // prints "1, 2"
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to mix both, that is re-use an existing binding for some of the variables in the pattern and create new bindings for others. Something like the following (which doesn't compile):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    println!("{}", x);
    (x, let y) = foo();
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Do you intend that the last line in the second example prints "0, 2" or "1, 2"?

Comment: You can shadowing the variable `x` just by using: `let (x, y)`. Is this not ok?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, the last line in the second example should print `1, 2`, since the `x` binding is re-used, hence `x` is now `1`.

Comment: @MarioSantini In my use case, `x` is declared in the parent scope, so I can't simply shadow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

[It was outlined as a future possibility in the RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2909-destructuring-assignment.html#future-possibilities), and discussed some times since, but neither RFC'd nor implemented.

There are two workarounds: either use `let` to declare all variables and assign one after, or use `let` before the assignment:

```rust
// Either:
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    println!("{}", x);
    let y;
    (x, y) = foo();
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}

// Or:
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    println!("{}", x);
    let (x2, y) = foo();
    x = x2;
    println!("{}, {}", x, y);
}
```